# Prevent refresh when submitting form by POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to embed the following form on a page, and when people press submit, the form submits via POST and then the page scrolls down to the next slide.

However the CMS which the form is based on forces a redirect when the form is submitted, which obviously takes the user away from my page.

How can I prevent the form from redirecting? I assume I would have to prevent the submit via e.preventDefault(); and then manually write some javascript to post the form, but confused as to how to do that. So far all my attempts have just stopped the form from submitting altogether.

```html
<form name="signup" class="bsd-signup-135" action="https://***" method="post" id="signup">
  <div class="fieldset" id="bsd-field-country">
    <div class="label"><label class="field">Country</label></div>
    <div class="input">
      <select id="country" name="country">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="AL">Albania</option>
        <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
        <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
        <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
        <option value="AO">Angola</option>
        <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
        <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
        <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
        <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
        <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
        <option value="AU">Australia</option>
        <option value="AT">Austria</option>
        <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
        <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
        <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
        <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
        <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
        <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
        <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
        <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
        <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
        <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
        <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
        <option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
        <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
        <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
        <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
        <option value="VG">British Virgin Islands</option>
        <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
        <option value="BN">Brunei</option>
        <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
        <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
        <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
        <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
        <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
        <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
        <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
        <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
        <option value="TD">Chad</option>
        <option value="CL">Chile</option>
        <option value="CN">China</option>
        <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
        <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
        <option value="KM">Comoros Islands</option>
        <option value="CD">Congo, Democratic Republic of the</option>
        <option value="CG">Congo, Republic of the</option>
        <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
        <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
        <option value="CI">Cote D'ivoire</option>
        <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
        <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
        <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
        <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
        <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
        <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
        <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
        <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
        <option value="TP">East Timor</option>
        <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
        <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
        <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
        <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
        <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
        <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
        <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
        <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
        <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
        <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
        <option value="FI">Finland</option>
        <option value="FR">France</option>
        <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
        <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
        <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
        <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
        <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
        <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
        <option value="DE">Germany</option>
        <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
        <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
        <option value="GR">Greece</option>
        <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
        <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
        <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
        <option value="GU">Guam</option>
        <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
        <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
        <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
        <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
        <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
        <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
        <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
        <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
        <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
        <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
        <option value="IN">India</option>
        <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
        <option value="IR">Iran</option>
        <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
        <option value="IE">Republic of Ireland</option>
        <option value="IL">Israel</option>
        <option value="IT">Italy</option>
        <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
        <option value="JP">Japan</option>
        <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
        <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
        <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
        <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
        <option value="KR">South Korea</option>
        <option value="XK">Kosovo</option>
        <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
        <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
        <option value="LA">Laos</option>
        <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
        <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
        <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
        <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
        <option value="LY">Libya</option>
        <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
        <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
        <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
        <option value="MO">Macau</option>
        <option value="MK">Macedonia</option>
        <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
        <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
        <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
        <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
        <option value="ML">Mali</option>
        <option value="MT">Malta</option>
        <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
        <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
        <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
        <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
        <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
        <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
        <option value="FM">Micronesia</option>
        <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option>
        <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
        <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
        <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
        <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
        <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
        <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
        <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
        <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
        <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
        <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
        <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
        <option value="AN">Netherlands Antilles</option>
        <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
        <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
        <option value="NE">Niger</option>
        <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
        <option value="NU">Niue</option>
        <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
        <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
        <option value="NO">Norway</option>
        <option value="OM">Oman</option>
        <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
        <option value="PW">Palau</option>
        <option value="PA">Panama</option>
        <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
        <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
        <option value="PE">Peru</option>
        <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
        <option value="PN">Pitcairn Island</option>
        <option value="PL">Poland</option>
        <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
        <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
        <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
        <option value="RE">Reunion</option>
        <option value="RO">Romania</option>
        <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
        <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
        <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
        <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
        <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
        <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
        <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
        <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
        <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
        <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
        <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
        <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
        <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
        <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
        <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
        <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
        <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
        <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
        <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
        <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
        <option value="ES">Spain</option>
        <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
        <option value="SH">St. Helena</option>
        <option value="PM">St. Pierre and Miquelon</option>
        <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
        <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
        <option value="SY">Syria</option>
        <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
        <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
        <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
        <option value="TW">Taiwan</option>
        <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
        <option value="TZ">Tanzania</option>
        <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
        <option value="TG">Togo</option>
        <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
        <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
        <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
        <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
        <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
        <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
        <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
        <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
        <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
        <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
        <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
        <option value="GB" selected="selected">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
        <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
        <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
        <option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
        <option value="VN">Viet Nam</option>
        <option value="VI">Virgin Islands (U.S.)</option>
        <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
        <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
        <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
        <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
        <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldset" id="bsd-field-email">
    <div class="label"><label class="field">Email</label></div>
    <div class="input"><input type="email" class="text" size="48" id="email" name="email"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldset" id="bsd-field-firstname">
    <div class="label"><label class="field">First Name</label></div>
    <div class="input"><input size="16" id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldset" id="bsd-field-lastname">
    <div class="label"><label class="field">Last Name</label></div>
    <div class="input"><input size="25" id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldset" id="bsd-field-custom-1963-group">
    <div class="label"><label class="field">Radio buttons:</label></div>
    <div class="input"> <input id="custom-1963_0" class="custom-1963" name="custom-1963" value="1" type="radio"><label for="custom-1963_0">Option 1</label> <input id="custom-1963_1" class="custom-1963" name="custom-1963" value="2" type="radio"><label for="custom-1963_1">Option 2</label>      <input id="custom-1963_2" class="custom-1963" name="custom-1963" value="3" type="radio"><label for="custom-1963_2">Option 3</label> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldset" id="bsd-field-email_opt_in">
    <div class="label"><label class="field"></label></div>
    <div class="input"><input id="email_opt_in" name="email_opt_in" type="checkbox" value="1"><label for="email_opt_in">Would you like to receive updates about our news, campaigns and appeals by email?</label></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldset" id="bsd-field-submit-btn">
    <div class="label"><label class="field"></label></div>
    <div class="input"><input name="submit-btn" value="Sign the petition" type="submit" id="submit_button"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I got this far with the javascript, but was unsure of how to post whether a field is checked or not, or how to post radios (especially radios with a hyphen in their name/ID, which I cannot change due to CMS.

```
$("#signup").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this),
    url = $form.attr("action");
  var posting = $.post(url, {
    country: $("#country").val(),
    email: $("#email").val(),
    firstname: $("#firstname").val(),
    lastname: $("#lastname").val()
  });

  posting.done(function(data) {
    alert("Success!");
  });
});
```

Comment: Hook an event handler to the `submit` event of the `form` element, then call `preventDefault()` on the event that's raised. You can then place your AJAX logic within that handler to be executed while the browser remains on the current page. If you want a specific example of how to do this, please show your current JS code so we can help you debug it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Just realised I hit save before pasting the whole question. Now updated the original with my JS. Am I headed in the right direction? If so, how do I get around check/radios with POST, and also the hyphen in the radio names?

Comment: You're definitely going in the right direction, in fact the code looks absolutely fine; there should be no redirection made from that code. I would suggest checking for errors in case your `preventDefault()` call is being blocked. I'd also check to make sure there's no other JS code being called when the form is submit which is actually making the redirect

Comment: To get around the hyphens in the input names, wrap the keys of the object in quotes, eg: `'custom-1963': $('.custom-1963:checked').val()`. Using `form.serialize()` may be of benefit too.

Comment: I've put it in quotes but it's not working. Form is submitting and POSTing all the data correctly, but that field is just showing blank...

Comment: Try just using `$.post(url, $form.serialize())`

Comment: Same issue when using serialise – all the other data is posting, but the custom field is not. CMS issue possibly?

Comment: Without seeing the page lifecycle it's hard to say. Unfortunately I can't really offer any further help, as what you've shown should be working fine.

Comment: Well thanks so much for trying anyway! At least I've learned how to do checkbox/radios.